# Key press events for GXT FileUploadField

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload, gxt

GXT 3.x only.

It is becoming apparent to me that Sencha had deliberately designed FileUploadField to shunt off all key press events from ever being detected.

I tried to intercept onBrowserEvent(Event) and could not detect any key press events which I would have generated by keypresses while having focus on the FileUploadField component.

Where is the key-press event shunt?

I could not find any keypress handler insertion methods.

I wish to allow triggering the file upload by either press on the space-bar or enter key.

Short of rewriting a whole new component from scratch, could someone advise me what I could do to achieve my goal of a keyboard activated file upload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onBrowserEvent` won't recieve any events unless you sink them - did you make sure to call `sinkEvents`? How are you adding handlers? If you use `addDomHandler`, it will sink them for you, but `addHandler` either assumes that they are not dom events, or that you already called `sinkEvents`. Without sinking an event, the browser doesn't know to pass that event on to a GWT widget. If *all* events were sunk automatically, then every time you moved the mouse across the page you would see a firestorm of events as mousemove fired for every widget you passed, and all of its parents.

If you override `onBrowserEvent`, then you are building the method that describes how to handle the actual event that comes from the browser - that is where the `com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM` class wires into the Widget to give it events. Short of making that method final, there is no way to prevent you, the widget user, from getting those events as long as the browser is generating them and passing them through the event listener.

Even if onBrowserEvent has been overridden and made final, you can *still* get access to many events by creating a `NativePreviewHandler` and checking where the event is occurring. This gets you in to the event before it even goes to the widget itself - there you can call `NativePreviewEvent.cancel()` to prevent it from happening on the widget itself, or you can handle it early in the handler.

Comment: I am able to use addDomHandler(handler, KeyDownEvent.getType()) on FileUploadField component, but it works only when focus is on textfield but not when on the button. I need to access the button to addDomHandler to it but the button is private.

Comment: JSNI can allow you to access private members of other objects... that said, if you are listening for key strokes on buttons and adding new behavior, I wonder if you should be making your own widget perhaps. BTW, the 'button' is a fake on the file upload field - you never actually click it since there is a file input drawn over it, hidden.